# Exclude third party script from finding and search

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider, jetbrains-rider

As the title goes: is there any way to limit search or find only for scripts of certain range/namespace? At first it was hardly an issue but as the project grew, its started to take up more and more effort to look for the right symbol.

Comment: If you're talking aboud Add Component menu in Inspector window, there is no way to change the hot search (when you typing letters after clicking the Add Component button), but you can decorate your class with `[AddComponentMenu(string menuName)]` attribute and specify the menu name and category, like `"Gameplay/Player"`. This hopefully will help to maintain some structure in your project.

Comment: you can try exclude from indexing action for a folder or a file in Rider (Context menu > Tools > Stop Index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDE probably should provide that feature, Unity itself does not have complex search. For example, in JetBrains Rider you [can search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Finding_and_Replacing_Text_in_Project.html) for a script or code part within a scope - directory, solution or project